# Php is not getting any information from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why in ,txt file (I'm using test mail server tool) displays line SELECT mail FROM check_out instead of mail address? Example is in the photo

EDITED CODE (STILL NOT WORKING):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT mail FROM check_out";
$to = "SELECT mail FROM check_out";

mail($to , "ORDER", "Your order is placed !","From: vape@v.com");
$_SESSION['message'] = "Order placed succesfuly"; 
header('location:index.php');

if  (isset($_GET['up'])) {
$orderid = $_GET['up'];
mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM check_out WHERE id=$orderid");
header('location:index.php');
}



$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks for the help

[How email address is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jH6y.png)

Comment: The `to` field is your SQL query... Unrelated to you question but you also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: Also you do nothing with `$result`, and why connect to the DB twice ($conn and `$db`)?

Comment: @chris85, but where is the main problem? Why this code isn't getting any information from database?

Comment: You do nothing with `$result` and the `to` field of your `mail` call is set to the SQL query. `mail($sql ,`

Comment: I've deleted $result row, second connection rows and changed sql to $to, but I'm getting same information as before:$sql = "SELECT adresas FROM check_out";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$to = "SELECT adresas FROM check_out";

mail($to , "ORDER", "Your order is placed !","From: vape@v.com");

Comment: Please update the question with the new code.

Comment: @chris85 just did it

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause here or you're just grabbing a random email address from your database.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: The code appears the same, 2 queries, no use of `$result`, and passing the query to the `mail` still (just with a different variable name).

Comment: @chris85 edited, but still the same

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely aware of the purpose of this script but I tried to fix it.
Maybe that helps:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
session_start();

$result = $conn->query('SELECT mail FROM check_out ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
$to = $result->fetch_assoc();

mail($to['mail'] , "ORDER", "Your order is placed !","From: vape@v.com");
$_SESSION['message'] = "Order placed successfuly"; 

if  (isset($_GET['up'])) {
    $Orderid = (int) $_GET['up'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM check_out WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $Orderid);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$conn->close();

header('location:index.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not working :Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_area\update.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_area\update.php on line 15

Comment: It seems that the query is failing. Then the query function will return false. Can you check the query, correct and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the help, you did save my day <3